# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

My project is fine if i *Rebuild/Make project* but i am getting ERROR while trying to build *.apk* file, even i am unable to Run my project on mobile and ADB. I tried including the apache.commons.codec package in my Android application and couldn't get it running. Android could not find method org.apache.commons.codec.binary.base64 and output the following errors.

> **Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.> org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64**

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
  }

 }
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.rozdoum.ibanewschat"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 21
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
 }

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
//compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
//  compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try cleaning and run

Comment: in studio termial, run  `gradlew assembleDebug` it will give the error cause

Comment: well thanks for the answers but this not work for me. gettng the same ERROR